# android: application crash when i hit back button (activitygroup + TabWidget)

Tags: android, tabbar, back, activitygroup

every one!

One year ago, I have developed an application with the combination "ActivityGroup + TabWidget", it works well on android os 2.3+. But I tested it on os 4.0, and I found it crash sometimes. 
- If I open application, I do nothing, and i hit "back", it works well.
- If I open application, navigate in the application (click on list item, see detail item then go back), and then when I am back to the "root" page of a tab, i click "back", it crash. (It should close the application normally) --------in this case, the activitygroup start new activity and recieve the back keyevent
- If I open application, navigate in the application like above, but juste see the views not started by activitygroup, but by the root activity in the group. Il works well.

There are some code in my ActivityGroup

```
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
// Start the root activity withing the group and get its view
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent)
                                        .getDecorView();
    // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
    replaceView(view);
}

public void back() {
    if(history.size() > 1) {  //history = new ArrayList<View>(); global variable
        history.remove(history.size()-1);
        setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));

        mIds.pop();
    }else {
        finish();    // I tried to commment it too, but no lucks
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        back();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And there's the error stack:

```
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not                 perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1213)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:442)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2121)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2099)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2557)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2329)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1859)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1361)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchKeyEvent(TabHost.java:298)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1859)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1361)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3273)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-18 18:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6828):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I didn't use Fragment, because it wasn't published by android sdk when i developped this application.

Any ideas? Every idea will be appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onBackPressed()` to achieve your desired results, you can use it in the following way.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
  //Your code here
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Most importantly make sure you have implemented this method in all of your child activities which will be used in your activity group.**

Comment: Yes you are right. I put onBackPressed() on each activity for use in ActivityGruop. And It work as expected.

Comment: It has been sometime I've been working in others projects. But thanks Muhammad, I'll try your solution when I get sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like this:

`if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)`

you can try handling the back press button by overriding

`public void onBackPressed() {}`

and write your code inside it.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it ... On which line it gives this error .... does it come inside back() method ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. When i hit back on root page of a tab, it didn't stop in anywhere, I made breakpoint at "back()" "OnStop()" "OnPause()" "OnKeyDown()" "onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) ", but nothing happend, it stopped directely at "FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss() line:1213" which I can not see de source code, juste a blank page.

Comment: But when I hit back button on the others pages (detail pages), it did stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can help this code:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```